# Creating Message System in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I m trying to create message system where I want to list down the users with whom one has interacted with recent chat on top I know this question is duplicate as well but i cant figure out where the problem is
Here is my message table structure

**`user_message`** table

```
msgID   sentBy  sentTo  message     sentTime 
1         3     1       Hii B      1493306882
2         3     1       Hi A       1493309615
1         1     3       Hmm        1493306882
2         1     3       Yeah       1493309615
```

and the query i tried is

**QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM user_message_status LEFT JOIN users ON user_message_status.userID=users.userID

LEFT JOIN user_message ON user_message_status.msgID=user_message.msgID WHERE user_message_status.userID='".$_SESSION['userid']."'

GROUP BY user_message_status.msgID ORDER BY user_message.msgID DESC
```

**PROBLEM**:

1) When userA send msg to userB, userA name is printed in chat list instead of recipient(userB)

2) The amount of msg sent or receive equals to the number of users are listed in the chat.

**user_message_status**: table

```
msgstatusID     msgID   userID  box     read    readTime
  1              1        3     outbox   0         0
  2              1        1     inbox    0         0
```

This is status table to read unread messages or delete

Comment: When user A sends message to User B then why do you want User B name with the message?

Comment: Ofcos their will be userB in userA outbox so that userA can get to know with whom userA has chat with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First update the query to the below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_message_status s
    LEFT JOIN users u  USING userID
    LEFT JOIN user_message m  USING msgID 
WHERE s.userID='".$_SESSION['userid']."'
GROUP BY user_message_status.msgID 
ORDER BY user_message.msgID DESC
```

Because both tables have the same column names, to make you sql shorter and neater, you can use the `USING` function
Both `LEFT JOIN users ON user_message_status.userID=users.userID` and `LEFT JOIN user_message ON user_message_status.msgID=user_message.msgID` was changed. We then renamed the tables to just a single letter so you don't have to write the entire table name.

Also why your userA is sent is because, your query will return, lets say I am id '3',

```
msgstatusID    msgID    userID  box     read    readTime
1              1        3       outbox  0       0
```

So from the joins, the `user_message` will return

```
msgID   sentBy  sentTo  message     sentTime 
1         3     1       Hii B       1493306882
1         1     3       Hmm         1493306882
```

So you would have to use an `if` statement or turnary operation for the name and say:

```
if (sentBy == $_SESSION['userid'])
    $name = sentTo;
else
    $name = sentBy;
```

OR

```
$name = (sentBy == $_SESSION['userid']) ? sentTo : sentBy;
```

Basically to show the proper name of who you are talking to, you need to first check which column name to use

AS for problem 2, if you want to limit the amount then you need to add more condition. Maybe you only want outbox so you need to put `AND box = 'outbox'`

The below sql should help you out

```
SELECT 
    s.msgId
    , m.message
    , (
        SELECT CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) 
        FROM users 
        WHERE userId = CASE WHEN m.sentTo = s.userId 
        THEN m.sentBy 
        ELSE m.sentTo END
    ) AS chatWith
    , m.sentTime
    , s.read
FROM user_message_status s
    LEFT JOIN user_message m USING (msgID)
WHERE s.userID='".$_SESSION['userid']."'
ORDER BY m.msgID DESC
```

Remove `LEFT JOIN users u  USING userID` because it will be sub queried

`s.msgID`       // used for deleteing the chat conversation

`m.sentBy, m.sentTo, m.message, m.sentTime`     // all important data for your messages

Comment: Is it my correct approach to do what i want ? I just want to dispay the username to whom msg was sent or receive from (Something like fb)

Comment: Your query can be updated a little based on what you really need but I have showed you in the answer how to get with whom you are chatting with by using the if statement. I just added a few more details to explain how to make you query neater :)

Comment: Please not that what i mentpons is only logic...it is not the actual code because to get the sentBy, you would habve to use the variable..

Comment: Yeah way you told using if else i think is complicated it would be great if I get what I want if my query is updated to what I really want

Comment: I m trying to achieve something like fb messenger where recent users are on top

Comment: Oh ok well yes, you can use a case when in you r sql statement to get the correct person. You query needs a complete re-do. I would use a select *. Because it returns too much data. Just select what you really need. I will update and add the sql I would use for you :)

Comment: Check the answer again

Comment: Their is syntax error though I corrected few column names with correct name

Comment: Well yea, I don't know the columns to you users table so I added my own so you know what I mean :D let me know what it is and I can add it to the update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142976/discussion-between-abhi-burk-and-callen).